# Extract sub-strings from Vulnerability Assessment log in Bash with multiple separators

Tags: string, bash, shell, awk, substring

I am a new intern just started learning scripting in **Bash**. I am working on some security log files with contain records in the following format:

```
Apr  9 14:11:44 10.10.12.10 NeXpose: VULNERABILITY: TCP timestamp response (generic-tcp-timestamp)
```

I am trying to extract two substrings, namely the target ip address and vulnerability description and write to a file using **awk**, I can extract either one in one run. Such as

```
awk '{print $4}' >> output
```

gives ip address

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = " VULNERABILITY: ";  OFS = "|"} /VULNERABILITY/ { print '"$MY_VAR"' $2}'>> output
```

gives the last part of the string

Is there a way that I can extract both in one sentence for ease of output?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it in perl:

```
perl -lne 'print $1." | ".$2 if(/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*VULNERABILITY:(.*)/)' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
Apr  9 14:11:44 10.10.12.10 NeXpose: VULNERABILITY: TCP timestamp response (generic-tcp-timestamp)
>
> perl -lne 'print $1." | ".$2 if(/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*VULNERABILITY:(.*)/)' temp
10.10.12.10 |  TCP timestamp response (generic-tcp-timestamp)
```

Comment: This is wonderful! But am I able to embed perl codes in bash scripts?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `cut` for this:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f5,8- file
10.10.12.10 TCP timestamp response (generic-tcp-timestamp)
```

The option `-d` sets the delimiter and `-f` lets you specify the field numbers. Here we want field 5 and everything from field 8. Use redirection to store the changes to a new file:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f5,8- file > outfile
```

Take a read of `man cut`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to split with character `:`. Last field is trivial, and for the IP split again with spaces and get second field, like:

```
awk -F: '{ 
    split( $3, f3, /[[:space:]]+/ ) 
    printf( "%s %s\n", f3[2], $NF ) 
}' infile
```

It yields:

```
10.10.12.10  TCP timestamp response (generic-tcp-timestamp)
```